# Istio circuit breaker sending traffic to unhealthy Services

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, istio

I'm quite new to istio and experimenting Istio circuit breaker concepts, for that I have configured the istio virtual service, destination rules and nginx pods.

My virtual service have two different nginx pods, I configured 50-50 traffic distribution, For testing the circuit breaker I scaled down my service B to zero, thought of expectation should route the traffic always to Service A. But It's not working a expected

I'm getting no healthy upstream error, whenever traffic routed to service B

Kindly find the configuration files for the same

**Deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment-1
  labels:
    app: nginx-deployment-1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
      version: "1"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
        version: "1"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx-1
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment-2
  labels:
    app: nginx-deployment-2
spec:
  replicas: 0
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
      version: "2"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
        version: "2"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx-2
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

**VirtualService.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: nginx-virtual-service
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
    - nginx-gateway
  http:
    - route:
      - destination:
          host: nginx-service
          subset: v1
          port: 
            number: 80
        weight: 50
      - destination:
          host: nginx-service
          subset: v2
          port: 
            number: 80
        weight: 50
      # retries:
      #   attempts: 3
      #   perTryTimeout: 1s
      #   retryOn: 5xx
      # timeout: 3s
      
**service.yaml**

    apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
  labels:
    app: nginx-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
      name: http-web
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

**destinationrule.yml**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: nginx-load-balancer
spec:
  host: nginx-service
  trafficPolicy:
    connectionPool:
      http:
        http1MaxPendingRequests: 1
        maxRequestsPerConnection: 1
      tcp:
        maxConnections: 1
    outlierDetection:
        baseEjectionTime: 60s
        consecutive5xxErrors: 1
        interval: 2s
        maxEjectionPercent: 100
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      version: "1"
  - name: v2
    labels:
      version: "2"
```

I'm getting the below error while routing the traffic to service B, Since I scaled down that pod to zero for testing, Not sure circuit breaker will trip and block the service B request and send all traffic only to Service A

[image]

Anyone pls advise on this ?